# After every change in file, all files are getting upload in network

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I am using React with Vite. I am having a weird issue whenever I change my file locally during development, all files(component, assets, etc.) are getting upload after every save. if anyone can help me, it would be great. Thanks in advance.

Following code is my vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteTsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import svgrPlugin from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgrPlugin()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    watch: {
      ignored: ["!**/node_modules/**"],
    },
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "./build",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: "/src",
      styles: "/src/styles",
      "@": "src/styles",
    },
  },
});
```

I want to know the reason behind the behaviour as after every save from file, result are displaying after 7-10 seconds and all files are getting uploading instead of only changed file.

Comment: Where are these files getting uploaded too?

Comment: You need to exclude watched directory inside server config. 
`watch: {
    exclude: ["path/to/directory"],
  },` Also remove `ignored: ["!**/node_modules/**"],`

Comment: @MohammedShahed to current(localhost:3000) tab. I guess they are getting upload for source map? I am not sure as well. I believe instead of chunk, files are getting upload.

Answer (score -2):

from what i can figure out from this is the server plugin in vite is responsible for the action as it's responsible for instant server start so it's updating everything so that there's no issue starting the server.